# Почему в массив попадают лишние элементы?

Tags: java, массивы

Хочу реализовать объединение с сортировкой 2 массивов. Мои методы main и сортировочный метод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   int [] arr1  = {1,2};
    int [] arr2  = {5,9,2,7,11,22};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(arr1,arr2)));

}
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
   int k=0, i=0, g =0;
    int lenght =a1.length + a2.length;
    System.out.println(lenght);
    int  res_mas [] = new int [lenght];

    while(g!=lenght){
        if(k<a1.length){
            res_mas[g] = a1 [k];
        }
        g++;
        if(i<a2.length){
            res_mas[g] = a2 [i];
        }
        g++;
        Arrays.sort(res_mas);
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    return res_mas; 
}
```

В консоли я получаю следующее:

```
    8
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 7]
```

Объясните пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка. У меня 2 предположения, либо в логике моего кода косяк,либо есть у метода `sort()` какой-то нюанс, который я не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проблема в том, что если массив закончился, в данном случае первый, то вы увеличиваете `g` на единицу и переходите к следующей проверке. Т.к. здесь массив из элементов примитивного типа, то там значение по умолчанию `0`, которое и добавиться в ваш массив.
2. странно после каждого прохода делать сортировку. тогда проще сначало все элементы залить в один массив и потом уже делать `sort`
3. Идея сортировки: если на вход подаются 2 отсортированных массива, то проще на каждом шаге сначало сравнивать текущие элементы исходных массивов между собой, добавлять тот который больше(или меньше, в зависимости от того в каком порядке хотите чтоб были элементы), увеличивать на 1 индекс того массива, элемент которого был залит в новый массив и переходить к следующему шагу. Понятное дело, что на каждом шагу необходимо проверять не закончились ли элементы в исходных массивах.

P.S. для таких случаев, чтобы понять в чем проблема, советую использовать `Debug` режим

Answer (score 0):

Можно малость сократить.

```
return Arrays.sort(ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second));
```